# How can I check if a filehandle is open in Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io, filehandle

Is there a way to check if a file is already open in Perl? 
I want to have a read file access, so don't require `flock`.

```
 open(FH, "<$fileName") or die "$!\n" if (<FILE_IS_NOT_ALREADY_OPEN>);
 #  or something like
 close(FH) if (<FILE_IS_OPEN>);
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Please see the [answer regarding `openhandle()` from `Scalar::Util`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5993224/47529).  The answer I originally wrote here was once the best we could do, but it's now badly outdated.

Comment: causes error: ... tell() on unopened filehandle ...

Comment: @ekerner technically not an error but a warning.

Comment: Scalar::Util (not the top-rated answer but should be) is the best way to do it for reasons stated in that answer.

Comment: See also https://perldoc.pl/IO::Handle.  $fh->opened.

Answer (score 24):

The [Scalar::Util](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epevans/Scalar-List-Utils-1.27/lib/Scalar/Util.pm) module provides the [`openhandle()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#openhandle) function for this.  Unlike [fileno()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fileno.html), it handles perl filehandles which aren't associated with OS filehandles.  Unlike [tell()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html), it doesn't produce warnings when used on an unopened filehandle    From the module's [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#openhandle):

> openhandle FH
>
> ```
> Returns FH if FH may be used as a filehandle and is open, or FH is a tied handle. Otherwise "undef" is returned.
>
>    $fh = openhandle(*STDIN);           # \*STDIN
>    $fh = openhandle(\*STDIN);          # \*STDIN
>    $fh = openhandle(*NOTOPEN);         # undef
>    $fh = openhandle("scalar");         # undef
> ```

Comment: [openhandle caveats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807231/how-can-i-test-if-i-can-write-to-a-filehandle/4200474#4200474)

Comment: This is the only real solution, thanks.

Comment: tchrist's answer to the question @daxim links is rather spectacular, but seems to only be different from openhandle in that it will tell you that the string "STDIN" is open (which it technically is, it seems, as you can use it for print etc.)  Now whether you would actually ever want to encourage this sort of thing is another question; I would tend to see the openhandle rejection of "STDIN" as more of a feature than a bug.

Comment: I came here from a Google search, and wanted to point out that the linked to `$handle->opened();` WFM.

Answer (score 11):

Why would you want to do that? The only reason I can think of is when you're using old style package filehandles (which you seem to be doing) and want to prevent accidentally saving one handle over another.

That issue can be resolved by using new style indirect filehandles.

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Couldn't open $filename: $!";
```

Comment: matt: try Perl::Critic for better style

Comment: Example reason why: Say you opened a filehandle with `open(FH, "-|")`. You want to make sure the forked process succeeds, which requires explicitly `close FH` to set `$!` or `$?` appropriately. If it didn't succeed, you want to raise an error; however, you don't want to raise an error if something else closed `FH` already.

Comment: Another use case: You successfully opened a file handle on an NFSv4 mounted filesystem, and the NFS server reboots. Sometimes the file handle becomes invalid (`EBADF`). How to detect that?

Answer (score 10):

Perl provides the [fileno](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fileno.html) function for exactly this purpose.

**EDIT** I stand corrected on the purpose of `fileno()`. I do prefer the shorter test

`fileno FILEHANDLE`

over

`tell FH != -1`

Comment: Well... not really.  It provides fileno for the purpose of getting the system file descriptor number.  Determining whether the filehandle is open is a side effect (just as it's a side effect of tell).

Comment: And not a completely reliable side-effect either. It's possible to have a filehandle that's open to something other than a filedescriptor, in which case `fileno` sensibly returns undef. Examples are tied handles and handles opened to scalars.

Comment: tell(FH) produces a warning with a closed filehandle. Using fileno() does not.

Answer (score 2):

Tell produces a warning (so does stat, -s, -e, etc..) with `use warnings` (-w)

```
perl -wle '
    open my $fh, "<", "notexists.txt"; 
    print "can stat fh" if tell $fh
'
tell() on closed filehandle $fh at -e line 1.
-1
```

The alternatives `fileno($fh)` and `eof($fh)` do not produce warnings. 
I found the best alternative was to save the output from `open`.

Comment: `eof` has side effects. See its docs.