# How do you check if a file is open using Perl?

Tags: perl, file

Given the name of a file, how can I determine if the file is currently opened or in-use? (I am talking about files rather than Perl file handles.)

Please note that I am looking for a general-purpose Perl solution rather than an operating system-specific one. At a minimum, I would like something that works both on Windows and GNU/Linux-based systems.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520196/how-can-i-check-if-a-filehandle-is-open-in-perl

Comment: @cppcoder: The question you are referring to seems to be about file handles being open. I'm talking about files in this question.

Comment: POSIX does not provide any way to do this.  Therefore, no portable solution is possible given the current portable O/S interface available. You’d have to craft some higher level approach that provides a single point of access for the opening bits. It’s like with lock files.

Comment: @tchrist, I think I'll accept your answer if you convert that comment into an answer.

Comment: What's the solution on Windows? I don't mind if it's Windows-specific?

Comment: @HelenCraigman, I don't know; I was looking for something cross-platform. At a guess, you might be able to [use the Windows API](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-API/). See [this Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12821767/238753) for a possible means to do this. I think it's better if you post this as a new Stack Overflow question about this since this question is not seeking a Windows-specific solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POSIX does not provide any way to do this. Therefore, no portable solution is possible given the current portable O/S interface available.

You’d have to craft some higher level approach that provides a single point of access for the opening bits. It’s like with lock files.

Answer (score 0):

See the following snippet (only Linux/Unix, you don't tell us which OS you run):

In a one-liner :

```
perl -e 'my $file = $ARGV[0]; print "file $file is opened" if `lsof $file`;' FILE
```

In a script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w

use strict;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
print "file $file is opened\n" if `lsof $file`;
```

To run it :

```
./script.pl FILENAME
```

Comment: That's probably a good way to do it on a Unix-based system. However, I'm using Windows. A general-purpose solution that doesn't depend on the operating system would be good.

Comment: There's a perl module : http://search.cpan.org/~marcb/Unix-Lsof-0.0.9/lib/Unix/Lsof.pm but works only on Unix & Unix likes. Maybe working with `cygwin` can helps there.

Comment: @flesk: Can you provide any more information about that module? Is it also Linux specific? If not, can you provide an example of using it to solve this problem?

Comment: On OpenBSD, it’s `fstat`, not `lsof`.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Scalar::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util)

The [Scalar::Util](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epevans/Scalar-List-Utils-1.27/lib/Scalar/Util.pm) module provides the [`openhandle()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#openhandle) function for this.  Unlike [fileno()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fileno.html), it handles perl filehandles which aren't associated with OS filehandles.  Unlike [tell()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html), it doesn't produce warnings when used on an unopened filehandle    From the module's [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#openhandle):

> openhandle FH
>
> ```
> Returns FH if FH may be used as a filehandle and is open, or FH is a tied handle. Otherwise "undef" is returned.
>
>    $fh = openhandle(*STDIN);           # \*STDIN
>    $fh = openhandle(\*STDIN);          # \*STDIN
>    $fh = openhandle(*NOTOPEN);         # undef
>    $fh = openhandle("scalar");         # undef
> ```

Comment: I had a look at that function, but it doesn't seem to address the question. However, it's possible that I simply don't know how to use the function to do what I'm asking.

Comment: Yes, sorry, wrong answer.

I suppose you'll have to look for windows-specific file opening functions from win32 api.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
use strict;
open(IN, ">test");
print IN "Hello";
close(IN);
if(fileno(IN) == undef )
{
    print "File is CLOSED\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm asking about files rather than file handles.

Answer (score -1):

I know it has been a while but for Windows I have had some pretty good luck detecting a file is being written to by trying to lock the file (nothing fancy - just open for read, use Perl internal flock and close the file).  this seems to work even on network files.  I am not so sure if this works for Linux (it might on a write) and I do not know if it can detect other file readers.

Answer (score -1):

I read tons of post but didn't find the solution I was looking for. In my case I have a for loop creating and closing tons of files. I wanted to check if my file handler that I created was open or not. This is how you do it

```
use IO::Handle;

if (something matches create a file)
{
  open( $signoff_report_html, '>', "$val21");
}
elsif ( ... )
{
  #keep doing amazing stuff
}
else
{
   if ($signoff_report_html->opened()) 
   {    
      #file is ok
      print "File is opened and ready\n";       
  }
  else 
  {
      print "File was closed ... ";
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to rename the file, will fail if it is open.

Answer (score -2):

I realize you don't want to open the file handle, but it is probably the simplest method IMO:

```
open my $myfh, '<', $my_file or die "Couldn't open $my_file: $!";
```

Comment: I think you can typically open files in read mode even if they're already open elsewhere.