# open filehandle if it doesnt exist, use it if it does

Tags: perl, if-statement, filehandle

I am scanning a file looking for certain values.  For each of those values, I want to create an output file and dump the matching line into that specific output file.  The values are unknown in advance so as I encounter them, I need to use them.

To keep from opening and closing files over and over, I am trying to test if a filehandle exists and if it does, write to it.  If it doesn't, open it, write to it and then use it again later if the same value comes up again.

My script is failing with these errors:

```
Scalar found where operator expected at get-authHost2.sh line 31, near ""$_ \n" $filehandle"
        (Missing operator before  $filehandle?)
Scalar found where operator expected at get-authHost2.sh line 35, near ""$_ \n" $filehandle"
        (Missing operator before  $filehandle?)
syntax error at get-authHost2.sh line 31, near ""$_ \n" $filehandle"
syntax error at get-authHost2.sh line 35, near ""$_ \n" $filehandle"
```

Here's what I have so far...

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $outfile; my $filehandle; my $authHost;

my $filename = $1; open(my $fh, '<', $filename)   or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";


while (my $line = <$fh>) {   chomp $line;
        if (my ($authHost) = $line = /authHost="(.*?)"/ )
        {
                print "$authHost" ;

                $outfile = print "$authHost-auth-events.out" ;

                $filehandle = $authHost;

                # if filehandle already exists, don't open the file again
                if (-f $filehandle) {
                        print "$line \n" $filehandle;
                  }
                  else {

                        open(my $filehandle, '>>', $outfile) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
                        print "$line \n" $filehandle;
                  }
        } } close $fh;
```

I can't seem to find an answer on this.  All of the questions I find are about testing if a file exists or not... not whether or not the file handle itself exists.

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm not a programmer, so be gentle!  :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a filehandle is open in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520196/how-can-i-check-if-a-filehandle-is-open-in-perl)

Comment: Store the file handles in a hash table, keyed by whatever makes sense - file name? Then uses `exists` to see if the given entry is present already.

Comment: `$filehandle = $authHost;` - You are missing a dictionary loopup. `$authHost` is a plain string and `$filehandle` is supposed to be a filehandle. I would suggest a `%filename_filehandle_map`

Comment: `$outfile = print "$authHost-auth-events.out"` is not doing what you seem to think it is, btw. And `print "$line \n" $filehandle;` has the arguments to `print` backwards. Filehandle first, then data to print.

Comment: @Zak Thanks for the suggestion.  I think that answer is a bit more complex than I needed here.  In this case, the if(-f $filehandle) works and was much easier for me, not being a programmer by trade, to understand and implement.  I'm still trying to figure out perl.  Baby steps.

Comment: @mike It doesn't actually work. It checks if a file exists, not a filehandle. Also, you say you are reusing filehandles, but you are not. A lexical filehandle is closed when it goes out of scope. You should be getting a warning about duplicating a variable name. Also, $outfile as defined in your code would be 1, the return value of print. $authHost would be empty, since you match against $_ when using = instead of =~. And your error does not match the code.

Comment: So when you say it works, I assume you are talking about some other code. As for your main problem, I would not worry about reusing filehandles. It will probably cause more problems and is a very minor optimisation, if any.

Comment: @TLP Thanks for the feedback.  Much has changed since this original post.  The assignment of $outfile was fixed given the feedback from Shawn above.  I also fixed the regex to use ~ as it was failing before.  If the filehandle check isn't working, can you provide an example that would check filehandle existence?  If there's a scope problem and the handles are getting closed anyway, maybe suggest how to better solve the problem.  It's a tricky one for me, not being a programmer, but searching all the googles still left me without answers... or answers that I could understand.  Thanks again.

Comment: @mike I did give you a suggestion. Just don't do it. Just keep using a lexical filehandle in a limited scope. Perl is very efficient when it comes to file operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My script is failing with these errors

You have the arguments backwards.

```perl
print "$line \n" $filehandle;
```

should be

```perl
print $filehandle "$line \n";
```

---

> then use it again later if the same value comes up again.

I'd use a hash to store the opened file handles (keyed by file name).

Keep in mind that that there's a limit on the number of open file handles a process can have.

Comment: *"Keep in mind that that there's a limit on the number of open file handles a process can have"*  --  I didn't know this,  or just haven't thought about it -- although it totally makes sense.  Pointing us curious ones to documentation as to a processes limit on file handles would be handy :)

Comment: @Zak, I can't provide the documentation for every system.

Comment: Not to be a noodge -- But with that said, is the comment a necessity?  I mean warning one that there's nth limit on nth widget ...   Eventually you'll hit the memory boundaries or processing rabbit holes on any "system" if not taking care of proper clean up / closures / trash collection ... Kind of goes without saying.  What makes file handles different in this case?

Comment: @Zak, Did you forget that the OP specifically wants to not close ("proper clean up") the handles so they can be reused? And the limit is much much much much smaller than "available memory". Thus the warning.